# renaming Windows machine and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server, rename

We've built a new Windows 2016 VM with SQL Server 2016 that we'll migrate a mission critical database currently on SQL Server 2008 R2 to. The original plan was to have users test, test, test and test each data feed coming in. There is pushback from our integration team on repointing the feeds because no one knows where they all are and of course never documented anything. The suggestion for the production cutover is to take the old Windows machine offline, rename the new Win server to the old Win servername , rename the SQL Server and hope everything works.

This idea of course frightens me and my position is I've never even heard of this being done and it's a great documentation opportunity.

Other than we'd be going into production with all the feeds untested, are there other caveats to doing this if I'm overruled?

Comment: How do you get the new environment in sync after testing? Restore again? And I'm not exactly 100% sure on the pushback from the integration team. They want you to cut over and then they'll fix the broken connections afterwards? Surely you want to test all components (especially renaming the server) before going live right?

Comment: No one has discussed [DNS Aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record)?

Comment: VTC'd as tip of the iceberg, but in the spirit of helping, I recommend reading [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77376) and [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/156043). What you're doing has been done _many_ times before by _many_ people, but a comprehensive list of all possible risks is... kind of a lot. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. Jacob, the plan is too restore again at cutover time and I most definitely want everything tested, the pushback is from those who don't. John E, cnames would probably be safer. Peter, just looking for some caveats.

Comment: Hi Joe - you should put @<user_handle> to ensure that people get notified of your responses - i.e. in this case, @JacobH (no spaces - it should appear in code-completion) - for your particular case - the name alone won't do it!

Comment: Thank you for the tip @Vérace. I'm new to asking questions here.

Comment: Message came through loud and clear! `I'm new to asking questions here.` Look forward to answering! :-) You might want to take the tour and also look at the meta site for tips on how to ask questions - good questions tend to get good answers!