# Copy SQL Logins and Permissions From One Server to Another

Tags: sql-server, permissions, logins, scripting

I need to duplicate all Logins and their associated database-level permissions from one server to another. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 for Server A and SQL Server 2012 for Server B I am able to find a few different scripts to transfer Logins from server A to server B. However, I nee to also transfer database-level permissions for each Login.

I've reviewed the following for transferring Logins:

http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/transferring-logins-to-a-database-mirror
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992

The SQL Soldier solution seems to work fine.

The same databases that reside on server A also reside on server B. how can I automate/script the Login and permissions transfer from one server to another?

Comment: `how can I automate/script the Login and permissions transfer from one server to another?` You can use `sqlcmd` and the top portion (only step 1) of the script from [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36701/8783) or using `Powershell` - script from [here](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Fully-TransferMigrate-SQL-25a0cf05)

Comment: How are the databases on Server A and Server B kept in sync? If you're using mirroring or AAG's then the database level is already done

Answer (score 1):

I created a series of stored procedures that accomplished a similar goal (with some powershell for flavor) based on this article [Claire-Hsu - SQL Logins](http://www.databasejournal.com/article.php/3921871/Claire-Hsu.htm)

I don't have a blog of my own (I know, I know) so I can't share my precise solution with you.  I essentially created three stored procedures.  One for the server logins, one for database and another for database object permissions.

Ah, shared on my one drive.  [Link to files](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4C9BB4C6B8071037!2286&authkey=!APMDuwYf9vUgFoY&ithint=folder%2Csql)  It's the stored procedures you need.  I have them in my DBA database.  I then use Powershell to get a list of logins, then query the stored procedure, save the script to a file and repeat.  You could easily change it to run the script on a different server.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a stored procedure you can use for the purpose.

[sp_dbpermissions](http://sqlstudies.com/free-scripts/sp_dbpermissions/)

When you run it it pulls all of the permissions for the database into three result sets.  The first is a list of principals, the second is role membership and the last is direct permissions (GRANT EXEC ON SP for example).  Each result set includes a script to remove said permission and another to create it.  Best of all it was designed originally as a research tool so there are lots of ways to restrict the data.  For example the parameter `@LoginName` will only return principals that match a given server principal name (as opposed to the database principal name) and even better for your purposes the **All** option for the `@DBName` parameter.  It not only runs the results for all databases (including system ones) but includes a `USE` statement at the beginning of the drop & create statements.

That way if you need to generate all permissions for a given login you can run this:

```
EXEC sp_DBPermissions 'All',@LoginName = 'loginame'
```

Note: This does not include the CREATE LOGIN statement.  To do that either use SQL Soldiers script or there is a sp_SRVPermissions as well.

Comment: Is there nothing from Microsoft to do this during a migration?